# R - Unable to select color using bgFill under createStyle command in openxlsx package

Tags: r

I am unable to select the color for the spreadsheet cells using the option bgFill.

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("workbook.xlsx")

s <- createStyle(bgFill = "#FFC7CE")
addStyle(wb,sheet = 1, s, cols=1:100, rows=1:100,gridExpand = TRUE)
```

Although I change the hex code on bgFill, my cells remain black in colour on the spreadsheet. I have tried predefined colours like red, green and blue too. I am unable to switch the colour of cells.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this strange issue after all? FTR I've just opened https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/197

Comment: Posting awalker89's comment here to save others the time "Yeah I'm not sure how excel uses bgFill - change it to fgFill and this will work."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For people who, years after, might encounter this problem like me...

As @IceCreamToucan states, you should use **fgFill** instead of bgFill which is for conditional formatting.
Openxlsx documentation writes for the createStyle function ([link](https://rdrr.io/cran/openxlsx/man/createStyle.html#:%7E:text=dash%2Ddot%20border-,bgFill,hex%20colour%20beginning%20with%20%22%23%22.%20%E2%80%93%20Use%20for%20conditional%20formatting%20styles%20only,-.)):

> bgFill:
> Cell background fill colour. A valid colour (belonging to colours()) or a valid hex colour beginning with "#". – **Use for conditional formatting styles only.**